# Extensão MongoDB para PHP 7.2.3 no Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: php, mongodb, ubuntu

Venho rodando o MongoDB junto como PHP no Ubuntu Server 17 há algum tempo. Recentemente instalei uma cópia do Ubuntu Server 18.04 e fiz o mesmo procedimento de instalação. Porém, mesmo incluindo extension=mongodb.so no php.ini, ele não carrega no phpinfo(), e não funciona quando tento executar o meu sistema.

Comment: Já deu uma olhada [aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mongodb.installation.pecl.php), mesmo tento habilitado a extensão ela precisa ser instalada também.

Comment: Realmente precisava instalar. Como não havia instalado no Ubuntu17.10 imaginei que não fosse necessário. Agora está tudo rodando. Vlw pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conforme contribuído por [fajuchem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/110834/fajuchem), faltava somente instalar a extensão.